# How can I draw a hyperboloid given its generatrix?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to see how a hyperboloid of revolution is generated by its generatrix, *i.e.* by rotating one (say the one passing point $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$) of the skew lines around another (say the *z* axis).

My trial:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
      {Sqrt[t^2 + (t + 1)^2] Cos@θ, Sqrt[t^2 + (t + 1)^2] Sin@θ, 1 + t}, 
      {t, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, β}, 
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2}}], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{1 - t, 1 + t, 1 + t}, {t, -1, 1}]
  ], 
  {β, 0.1, 2 π}
]
```

However, the generatrix $(1 - t, 1 + t, 1 + t)$ doesn't match the hyperboloid. So how can I do it correctly?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me but I suggest that you look at, for example, ["Generating a Hyperboloid by Rotating a Line"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GeneratingAHyperboloidByRotatingALine/) from the Wolfram Demonstrations Project.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "processor"?

Comment: @Silvia I guess the OP means "generator" but it's not clear if they want to generate the conic by rotating the line through the specified points (which doesn't match the plotted line incidentally) about the z-axis or vice versa.

Comment: @Tangshutao Hi could you please tell your question in Chinese to me in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?

Comment: @Silvia,抱歉，英语不好，我是想看通过（1，0，0）和（0，1，1）的空间直线绕z轴旋转的过程，看看它是怎么形成一个曲面

Comment: @Tangshutao I've edited your question according to your description. Please feel free to improve it if I misrepresented your meaning. If you feel ok, you can apply **reopen** your question. btw. I think MikeLimaOscar's link should have well answered it.

Comment: @silvia Is the title of the question correct? Or should 'processor' be replaced by generatrix?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ooh sorry! I missed it!

Comment: @Silvia,+1,That's my thought！

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wolfram example is quite slow, this is simple example with better performance.
Since you want to use point positions, I've also added `InputField`s for this purpose:

```
DynamicModule[{b1, b2, a, ds},
 Row[{
   Graphics3D[{
     Thick, Black, DotDashed, Line[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -2}}], Red,
     {Dynamic@GeometricTransformation[
        {Tube[{b1, b2}, .03], 
         Line@{b1, {0, 0, b1[[3]]}}, Line@{b2, {0, 0, b2[[3]]}}},
        RotationTransform[a Degree, {0, 0, 1}]
     ]},
     Thick, Orange, Dashing@1, Dynamic@ds[[ ;; IntegerPart[a/10]]]

     }, PlotRange -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 300, Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}}]
   ,
   Column[{Slider[Dynamic@a, {0, 350, 2}],
           InputField[Dynamic@b1],
           InputField[Dynamic@b2]}, Center]}],

   Initialization :> (
    b1 = {1, 1, -1}; b2 = {-1, 1, 1}; a = 1;
    ds := Table[Rotate[Line@{b1, b2}, a1 Degree, {0, 0, 1}], {a1, 0, 350, 10}];
    )]
```

[image]

Modifying Silvia's code:

```
Manipulate[

 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[(RotationTransform[th, {0, 0, 1}].RotationTransform[t1, {1, 1, 0}]
           )@{1, 1, t}], 
          {t, -2, 2}, {th, 0, 2 \[Pi]},PlotRange -> 2.5, ImageSize -> 500,
          Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}}, PlotStyle -> None, 
          MeshStyle -> Thick, Mesh -> {0, 50}
  ],
  {t1, 0, Pi, .05}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Tangshutao I've added another example, it might be quite illustrative.

Comment: Love the envelope! In the old days, this property was amply demonstrated by running a ruler through a plaster model of the one-sheet hyperboloid. What you have is the modern take. :)

Comment: @J.M. Sounds nice, I wish I had such examples at school.

Comment: I think anybody with enough willingness, a *Mathematica* installation, and a working 3D printer should be able to experience the "old-school" demo. :)

Answer (score 10):

Also a direct coordinate transformation from $(x,y,z)$ to $(t,\theta,z)$:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[
  RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}]@
   {1 - t, t, t}
  ], {t, -1, 2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: one sheet hyperboloid]

In fact, as long as you keep the tranform parameters away from $t$, the results will always be [ruled surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) (and the hyperboloid of one sheet is doubly ruled surface):

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[
  RotationTransform[0.3, {Sin[10 θ], 3 Cos[θ], 4 Sin[θ]}]@
   RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}]@
    {1 - t, t, t}
  ], {t, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
  PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: general ruled surface]

Answer (score 9):

One-liner:

```
n = 100; h = 1; r = 1; φ = 0.9 π;

Graphics3D@Line@Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &@{{r Sin[#], r Cos[#], 0 # - h}, 
    {r Sin[# - φ], r Cos[# - φ], 0 # + h}} &[2 π N@Range[n]/n]
```

[image]

---

A small fun with it: the hyperbolic [Shukhov Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukhov_Tower)

```
n = 16;
h = 5.0;
k = 5;
m = 3;
p = 1.5;

Graphics3D@Line@Flatten[#, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3}}] &@Table[{
     {(t - 1)^p Sin@RotateLeft[#, m], (t - 1) Cos@RotateLeft[#, m],0 # - h (t - 1)^p},
     {t^p Sin[#], t Cos[#], 0 # - h t^p},
     {t^p  Sin@RotateRight[#], t Cos@RotateRight[#], 0 # - h t^p}, 
     {(t - 1)^p Sin@RotateRight[#, m + 1], (t - 1) Cos@RotateRight[#, m + 1],
       0 # - h (t - 1)^p}}, {t, k}] &[2 π N@Range[n]/n]
```

[image]

Comment: Everything's a one-liner if you have a wide enough screen ;)