# The curve rotates around a straight line

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The red curve rotates around the black straight line,like this

[image]

in mathematicas :

- Red curve is named **generatrix**
- Black Line is named **Rotation axis**

Now I have the mathematical expressions of the generatrix and the straight line

generatrix :
$$
y=-0.024501 x^2+1.7508 x+220.159 \\
z=-0.02247 x^2-4.788 x+713.4127
$$

line:
$$
x=\frac{y-15.668}{3.248}=\frac{z-521.831}{-3.224}
$$

form line I konw Vector of a line is s={1, 3.248, -3.244}

I now draw them in the picture,like this

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
y = -0.024 x^2 + 1.75 x + 220.15;
z = -0.022 x^2 - 4.78 x + 713.41;
s = {1, 3.248, -3.244};

ParametricPlot3D[{{x, 3.248 x + 15.668, -3.224 x + 521.8}, {x, y, 
   z}},
 {x, -100, 100},
 (*=== axes ===*)
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 (*=== plotrange ===*)
 PlotRange -> {{-500, 500}, All, All},
 (*=== lengends ===*)
 PlotLegends -> {"Line", "Generatrix"},
 (*=== basestyle ===*)
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 15, Italic}
 
 ]
```

[image]

What I need to do now is to **rotate the red curve around the black straight line**, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Check document of `RotationTransform`

Comment: @xzczd I have searched this post, and I feel it is not what I want

Comment: You should put more effort in understanding the post and the document of `RotationTransform`: `line = {x, 3.248 x + 15.668, -3.224 x + 521.8}; func = RotationTransform[θ, s, line /. x -> 0]; ParametricPlot3D[{line, func@{x, y, z}} // Evaluate, {x, -100, 100}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}]` Here I've used the same method as shown in [Silvia's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38727/1871), except that I've added 3rd argument of `RotationTransform`, which is documented.